# add field to woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question.

I'm new with wordpress and especially with woocommerce.
Its a website I am doing for a friend of mine and now I am just into doing the best of it.

I wanna add an input (date) on the product page so that the customer can select an amount of products date and then proceed to cart.

On cart, there's a table with product bought so I want to display the "input date" there.

and when he purchase it will be updated in to order's DB.

Is there a way to achieve it ?

Comment: http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

Comment: ive seen this one, but i need the input at the product page for the cotumers.